# Recording app - React native - Sound doesn't save properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, audio-recording, recording

I'm building a recording application. After the first record, the sound can be found and playback in the record list. But after i create a new record and save it, the previous sound could not be played anymore. Does anyone know the problem? Was i wrong on storing it? I can share the git repo if anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance! Below are pieces of code on how i create and store the sound:

**CREATE SOUND FILE

//export a sound array with information about the sound for further use

export let soundArray = [];

//This is the function where after users hit play and stop recording, it will generate a sound file

async _stopRecordingAndEnablePlayback() {

```
this.setState({
  isLoading: true
});
try {
  await this.recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
} catch (error) {
  // Do nothing -- we are already unloaded.
}
const info = await this.recording.getURI();
console.log(`FILE INFO: ${JSON.stringify(info)}`);
await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
  allowsRecordingIOS: false,
  interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
  playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
  playsInSilentLockedModeIOS: true,
  shouldDuckAndroid: true,
  interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
  playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
  staysActiveInBackground: true
});
const { sound, status } = await this.recording.createNewLoadedSoundAsync(
  {
    isLooping: true,
    isMuted: this.state.muted,
    volume: this.state.volume,
    rate: this.state.rate,
    shouldCorrectPitch: this.state.shouldCorrectPitch
  },
  this._updateScreenForSoundStatus
);
this.soundInfo = info;
this.sound = sound;

this.setState({
  isLoading: false
});
```

}

//In JSX where users press 'create new sound' button, new sound will be created and the informations of current sound will be push into the array in the beginning and export for further uses

```
const newSound = {

       id: uuidv1(),
       name: this.state.name,
       desc: this.state.desc,
       sound: this.soundInfo
};


this.sounds.push(newSound);


soundArray = this.sounds;
```

**RECORDING LIST FILE

//import from create sound file

```
import { soundArray } from "./CreateRecord";
```

//JSX of the file, list of records and when users press one of them it will lead to chosen sound file:

```
<View style={styles.background}>
  <Text>List Records</Text>
  <FlatList
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    data={soundArray}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("CurrentRecord", { id: item.id })
          }
        >
          <ListItem chevron title={item.name} description={item.desc} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }}
  />
</View>
```

**CURRENT RECORD FILE

//import sound array from create sound file

```
    import { soundArray } from "./CreateRecord";


    export default class CurrentRecord extends React.Component {

    ...

    render() {

        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const id = navigation.getParam("id");
        this.sound = new Audio.Sound();

        if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {
          for (let i = 0; i < soundArray.length; i++) {
            if (soundArray[i].id === id) {
              this.currentSound = soundArray[i];
              console.log(this.currentSound);

              break;
            }
          }
          this.sound.loadAsync(this.currentSound.sound);
          this.sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this._updateScreenForSoundStatus);
          return <View style={styles.emptyContainer} />;
        }

        if (!this.state.haveRecordingPermissions) {
           return(

...
// this is where user press play

    <View style={styles.playStopContainer}>
                  <TouchableHighlight
                    underlayColor={BACKGROUND_COLOR}
                    style={styles.wrapper}
                    onPress={this._onPlayPausePressed}
                  >
                    {this.state.isPlaying ? (
                      <Foundation name="pause" size={58} />
                    ) : (
                      <Foundation name="play" size={58} />
                    )}
                  </TouchableHighlight>)
    ...)
```